# Orthodox written form of Sanskrit character Kleem?

Tags: sanskrit, bijakshara

I'm preparing a Yantra with which one can do "inner" Tratak on Kleem during the Sadhana of Kleem. One needs to draw a triangle pointing downwards with Kleem inside of it. Now I'm not sure enough which one to draw since there are two choices:

[image] or [image] .

Which one is more orthodox? I believe the orthodox one can produce the original effect that it should have- the power of characters, when we meditate on it.
Please help me choose the right one. Many thanks.

Comment: It is advisable to contact an expert in this subject in your locality.  As answer to this question will be opinion based, this question is liable to be closed.

Comment: Both are correct. Basically you are joining two letters and adding a swara. So both would have equal potency

Comment: The photograph is good for visualization purpose you can go ahead with that.

Comment: Second way is more reliable and both pronunciation is different . Second way is correct. You are only one in internet who is seeking for right path on this.